# How to concatenate data from a SQL Server XML query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, string-concatenation, sqlxml

I have a SQL query that returns me the XML below

```
<row>
  <urlSegment>electronics</urlSegment>
  <shortenedUrlSegment>0x58</shortenedUrlSegment>
</row>
<row>
  <urlSegment>phones</urlSegment>
  <shortenedUrlSegment>0x5AC0</shortenedUrlSegment>
</row>
<row>
  <urlSegment>curvy-simplicity</urlSegment>
  <shortenedUrlSegment>65546</shortenedUrlSegment>
</row>
```

etc

The output that I want is is a table with two columns (Url and ShortenedUrl) with the data concatenated in a url fashion as shown below.

```
Url                                  | ShortenedUrl
electronics/phones/curvy-simplicity  | 0x58/0x5AC0/65546
```

etc

Can anyone help?

Best of regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use xquery like this:

```
select
    stuff(
        @data.query('
            for $i in row/urlSegment return <a>{concat("/", $i)}</a>
        ').value('.', 'varchar(max)')
    , 1, 1, '') as Url,
    stuff(
        @data.query('
            for $i in row/shortenedUrlSegment return <a>{concat("/", $i)}</a>
        ').value('.', 'varchar(max)')
    , 1, 1, '') as ShortenedUrl
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22067)</kbd>**

Comment: Even thought I am not using XML anymore, this works lovely. Thanks.

Comment: Was doing this another way that wouldn't handle multiple sub-groups of strings to concatenate and this completely solved the issue. Much cleaner than before also. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely lovely!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @input XML

SET @input = '<row>
  <urlSegment>electronics</urlSegment>
  <shortenedUrlSegment>0x58</shortenedUrlSegment>
</row>
<row>
  <urlSegment>phones</urlSegment>
  <shortenedUrlSegment>0x5AC0</shortenedUrlSegment>
</row>
<row>
  <urlSegment>curvy-simplicity</urlSegment>
  <shortenedUrlSegment>65546</shortenedUrlSegment>
</row>'

SELECT
    Url = XRow.value('(urlSegment)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    ShortenedUrl =XRow.value('(shortenedUrlSegment)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/row') AS XTbl(XRow)
```

The `.nodes()` gives you a sequence of XML fragments, one for each `<row>` node in your XML. Then you can "reach into" that `<row>` element and fish out the contained subelements.

Comment: That gets me 1/2 way there, but I need to concatenate each row in each column so the data in both columns would be (Url)electronics/phones/curvy-simplicity & (UrlShortened) 0x58/0x5AC0/65546